# Creating disk images as a normal user

Tags: mount, permissions, loop-device

I want to be able to run the following script as normal user (as root it runs fine):

```
#!/bin/sh

dd if=/dev/zero bs=8192 count=128 of=disk.img
mkfs -t ext2 -F disk.img
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
mount /dev/loop0
echo aaaa > /mnt/aa
umount /mnt
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

To that end, I

1) added appropriate entry to /etc/fstab (only then normal user can run 'mount /dev/loop0' ):

```
/dev/loop0  /mnt  ext2    defaults,loop,users,noauto      0 0
```

2) added the user in question to the 'disk' group (only then the user is able to run 'losetup' - /dev/loop0 is owned by the 'disk' group)

Now, hopefully the last problem is that when I run as normal user, I get 'permission denied' error from 'echo'. No wonder, because after mounting, the permissions of the /mnt directory change to 755 root:root, and obviously a normal user cannot create files inside.

How should I create my 'disk.img' so that when mounted it is writeable by the very user that created it?

**Edit:**

The proposed 'pmount' solution appears to have the same problem. Reproduction steps:

1) install 'pmount' and add '/dev/loop0' to /etc/pmount.allow

2) run the following as a normal user:

```
#!/bin/sh

dd if=/dev/zero bs=8192 count=128 of=disk.img
mkfs -t ext2 -F disk.img
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
pmount -w /dev/loop0
echo aaaa > /media/loop0/aa
pumount /media/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

You will still get 'permission denied' from echo for the same reason we got it before - the permissions of the /media/loop0/ directory are 755:

```
[user@server test]$ ls -l /media/
total 1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 1024 Jul 22 13:40 loop0
[user@server test]$ ls -l /media/loop0/
total 12
drwx------ 2 root root 12288 Jul 22 13:40 lost+found
```

**Edit2:**

I managed to solve this - option 'root_owner' to mkfs.ext3 comes in handy:

```
#!/bin/sh

WHOAMI=`whoami`

uid=$(id -u $WHOAMI)
gid=$(id -g $WHOAMI)

dd if=/dev/zero bs=8192 count=128 of=disk.img
mkfs.ext3 -E root_owner=$uid:$gid disk.img
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
mount /dev/loop0
echo aaaa > /mnt/aa
umount /mnt
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Then after mounting the mountpoint is owned by the user who is running the script, and then the user is able to write inside :)

Comment: Regarding 2: by adding users to `disk` group those users can read private data straight from `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Good point; this shouldn't be too much of a problem , because the script will only be run from a Web-based frontend (and the server is in our intranet), and never by actual logged-in users, but maybe you'd have some suggestion how to tighten this up?

Comment: Ok. It was just a fair warning. Never know who ends up reading your question and go "oh that is useful" ;-) 1 thing that might be something: you could probably do this in a chroot too. Then you'd have "root" active inside that chroot and wont be bothered with permissions too.

Answer (score 3):

Use [pmount](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount) instead of `mount`.

> pmount ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard mount program which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a matching `/etc/fstab` entry.

Probably want the ...

> `-w`, `--read-write`
>
> Force the device to be mounted read/write. If neither -r nor -w is specified, the kernel will choose an appropriate default.

So you can drop the fstab entry and do not need to add the user to the `disk` group.

It allows mounting anywhere under `/media/` if the device is listed in `/etc/pmount.allow` so it will also solve any permissions problems.

Comment: One more question actually - see below...

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work - the same problem as before - see Edit...

Answer (score 2):

Rinzwind: my stripped-down script I posted in the question above doesn't show it, but there's a problem with the 'pmount' solution.

The problem is that it only appears to be able to mount to /media.

The full script is more complicated: it creates a 500MB large image file (image of a USB pendrive), partitions it into 2 partitions (FAT32 and Ext3) , mounts both to TMPFS (/tmp/loop0p1 and /tmp/loop0p2) and writes a loooot of data inside.

It is important to be able to mount to TMPFS so that this operation is fast - in my experience, doing it inside TMPFS makes this more than 10 times faster than doing it in actual block device in a HD.

/media is not TMPFS...

Comment: You could make /media tmpfs (not sure if that will mess with other things though :D ). Please don't use answers for questions; edit your question to add more info to it ;)

Comment: Yes, I could... This server is not used for anything else than producing those USB images from a Web-frontend, so I guess /media will never be used by anything but my script.